# Is there a maximum number of intents for a LUIS model? And/or Is there a recommended max?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

Creating a LUIS model and wondering if there is a maximum number of intents you can make. I found some very old links searching the interwebs that say 20 is the max. Is 20 still the max today? If the max is higher, or there is no max, is there a best-practice recommendation?

Answer (score 2):

Maximum is 500 intents and 100 entities per application 
https://blog.botframework.com/2018/01/16/luis-quick-start-list-entities/

Answer (score 2):

> Creating a LUIS model and wondering if there is a maximum number of intents you can make.

As rajesh mentioned, the maximum number of intents that a LUIS app can support is 500, but 100 entities per application is for **Simple** entity. For other types of entities’ limit, you can check [LUIS boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-boundaries).

[image]

Besides, if you [need more than the maximum number of intents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-concept-best-practices#if-you-need-more-than-the-maximum-number-of-intents), you can divide your intents into multiple LUIS apps and use different LUIS app for your different system. Or you can merge some similar intents to reduce the number of intents.

Comment: Worth adding that if you have a model reaching up to > 50,60 intents, you may want to consider splitting the app into two. We've seen NLU performance degrade around this point. Maybe it was on us, but worth paying attention to.